# VBA EXCEL Макрос удаляющий все пробелы в нужных фразах

Tags: vba, visual-basic, макросы

Никак не могу написать макрос,который бы работал как надо.
По сути макрос должен быть аналогом "найти и заменить",но в моих объемах данных каждый раз вставлять значения и вручную убирать пробел слишком долго.
Задача заключается в том,чтобы удалить все пробелы из введённого в поле выражения.
То есть,к примеру из фраз "Небо голубое облачное" "Небо голубое ясное" сделать "Небоголубое облачное" "Небоголубое ясное" введя "Небо голубое".С VBA дела никогда не имел,поэтому если можно,попроще как-то объясните,пожалуйста.
Есть такой код:

```
Sub DeleteSpaceBetweenWords2()
'Update by Extendoffice 2018/5/24
    Dim myWord As String
    Dim Spaceless As String
    Dim xRg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Cells
    xFind = Application.InputBox("Введите слово:", "Удаляем пробелы", , , , , 2)
    xRep = Replace(xFind, " ", "")
    If xFind = "False" Or xRep = "False" Then Exit Sub
    xRg.Replace xFind, xRep, xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False, False
End Sub
```

Но у него несколько проблем:
1)Если у фразы несколько пробелов,то ничего не произойдет,так как в реплейсе указан только один пробел.
2)Если в ячейке несколько выражений для которых надо удалить пробелы,удалит он только у первой попавшейся в ячейке фразы.

Comment: *...удалит он только у первой попавшейся...* Посмотрите параметры для метода [**.Replace**](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) - в коде, который вы показали используется `xlPart`, возможные варианты `xlPart` и **xlWhole**. Попробуйте... Кроме того, обратите внимание, что метод возвращает логическое значение. Это позволит в цикле `While` сначала заменить все двойные пробелы на одиночные, а уже после этого применить замену к нужной строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не получится, если учитывать условия: *Если у фразы несколько пробелов* и *Если в ячейке несколько выражений для которых надо удалить пробелы*

Перед заменой нужно каждую фразу чистить от лишних пробелов. Это можно сделать в цикле с помощью `Application.Trim` (*VBA*-шный `Trim` удаляет только крайние пробелы)

```
Sub DeleteSpaceBetweenWords2()
    Dim xFind As String, xRep As String
    Dim xRg As Range, c As Range
    
    xFind = Application.InputBox("Введите текст:", "Удаляем пробелы", , , , , 2)
    xFind = Application.Trim(xFind)
    xRep = Replace(xFind, " ", "")
    If xRep = "" Or xRep = "False" Then Exit Sub
    
    Set xRg = Range("C2:D20")
    
    For Each Cell In xRg
        Cell.Value = Replace(Application.Trim(Cell.Value), xFind, xRep)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Примечание: в текстах будут удалены все повторы пробелов.

`Set xRg = Cells` - так Вы загоняете в память все ячейки листа (16 384*1 048 576). Диапазон нужно или задавать, или вычислять его границы.

Работа с объектами листа медленная. Если диапазон большой, его записать в массив, там произвести обработку и выгрузить обратно уже полученный результат